# Spring Boot / Thymeleaf - Authentication Difficulties with Javascript Request and X.509 Auth

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web app that is configured to use .x509 certificate authentication.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/css/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().x509()
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),");

    }
}
```

UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        var userVal = userRepo.getUser(username);
        if (!userVal.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user with name: " + username);
        }
        var user = userVal.get();
        return new User(user.getUsername(), "",
                user.getRoles().stream().map(r -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

}
```

I have the app working for the most part; that is, I can access full pages requiring authorization with this setup. The issue arises when I attempt to load a fragment using JavaScript/TypeScript. When I click on the button that triggers the JS call, I receive the following error:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-09-17T14:08:44.019+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/employee/search"}
```

The JS/TS snippet

```
function loadEmployees() {

    const container = document.getElementById("resultPanel");
    const url = "employee/search";
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },
        body: JSON.stringify(buildBody())
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => container.innerHTML = res);

}
```

The template where the fragment is inserted:

```
<div id="page" class="container">

    <h1>Employee Search</h1>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class='form-row my-3'>
            <label for="reqType">Search Type: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="reqType" id="reqType">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option value=1>SSN</option>
                <option value=2>Name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
     /// Code omitted for brevity
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
    </div>
```

The fragment itself:

```
<div th:fragment="results-list">
    <div class="row d-md-flex flex-header d-none">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            Name
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Loc.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            DB
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex" th:each="emp : ${employees}">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="font-weight-bold d-inline d-md-none pr-1">Name: </span>
            <span th:text="${emp.lastName} + ', ' + ${emp.firstName} + ' ' + ${emp.middleName}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-2">
            <span class="font-weight-bold d-inline d-md-none pr-1">Loc.: </span>
            <span th:text="${emp.location}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span class="font-weight-bold d-inline d-md-none pr-1">DB: </span>
            <span th:text="${emp.dbName}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="font-weight-bold d-inline d-md-none pr-1">Edit: </span>
            <a th:href="@{'/employee/' + ${emp.id}}">View <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <hr />
    <h2 class="mt-1">Results</h2>
    <div id="resultPanel" class="mt-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

..and the Controller that loads the fragment:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;

    @PostMapping("/search")
    public String searchByName(@RequestBody SearchDTO dto, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employees", empService.searchEmployees(dto));
        return "fragments/results-list";
    }
```

Please note, I realize JavaScript and Java are very different languages; I am including both tags given that I am not positive whether the change must be performed client or server side. Feel free to remove one if you do not believe such is appropriate.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I should ask a qualifier: is employee/search intended to be public or secure?

Comment: @JECarterII, it is intended to be secure.  Thanks.

Comment: Do any other JS accessed end points produce a 403?

Comment: If static pages work but AJAX requests fail, it may be a missing header in the fetch().  I'm searching now on that but not finding a lot of help.

Comment: @JECarterII, unfortunately, that is the only piece of JS in the app that accesses an endpoint on the server/makes an AJAX request. Thanks much for your help. I will look and see what I can find as well regarding fetch() headers.

Comment: One thing you might try, as I have no x509 setup to try this myself, fire up Chrome or Firefox Debugger and look at the request headers passed from your static page requests that result in 200.

Comment: Also, just want to confirm your UI and API are running under the same domain name such that .cors() would not be needed on your security config.

Comment: @JECartterII, yes, they are running on the same domain. I tried comparing the headers of a successful request to the JS driven 403 request. The only difference I noticed was the presence of 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1` for the successful ones. I edited the headers for the JS request, but unfortunately, still received a 403.  Will try digging into the requests/responses a bit more with the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had run into the same issue and found I needed to specify my secured resources before my open resources.

So you might have better luck with the following:

```
httpSecurity
    .csrf().disable()   
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().x509()
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/css/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
    ;
```

See the [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-form).

Edited per feedback to make this a compiler friendly code sample.

Edit #2 - added .csrf().disable().  I've had to do this myself for REST to work, and see others have also.

Comment: Thank you much for the response, but unfortunately, it is still producing the same error. I had to relocate the "userDetailsService" portion to immediately come after the .x509 part to get it to compile, but received the same 403 after that.

Comment: @KellyM You might also consider adding .csrf().disable() immediately after httpSecurity   as seen here: https://www.codesandnotes.be/2014/10/31/restful-authentication-using-spring-security-on-spring-boot-and-jquery-as-a-web-client/

Comment: Adding `csrf().disable()` did it. Thanks so much. Wish I could give you more than simply accepting an answer. Just a note to any future readers: please understand the implications of disabling CSFR. This is a very important security feature; I personally will be adding some code to account for this. However, just simply appending it was, at least, enough to confirm the root cause of my problems.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad you were able to get it going.  Yes, I would very much like to understand better how to work properly with csrf and ajax as well.